# SQL Assembly WebResponse and String Parsing VERY slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, httpwebrequest, sqlclr

So I am quickly learning the ways of C# (complete noob that inherited this problem); I have written up the following code which calls a web service that returns JSON that is not always well-formed. The mission here is to take the JSON string and break it into array segments which get inserted into an SQL table for further parsing and testing. I.e. if the return string was something like

```
   {1234:{5678:{1:{"key":"val","key":"val"},{2:{"key":"val","key":"val"}}}}
```

then the rows would be:

```
{1234}
{5678}
{1:{"key":"val","key":"val"}
{2:{"key":"val","key":"val"}
```

This is .NET 3.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2 (Legacy stuff).
Here is my working code:

```
 public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
    {
         [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = 
    DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlString TestParse(SqlString uri, SqlString username, SqlString passwd, SqlString postdata)
    {
            //-----
           // The SqlPipe is how we send data back to the caller
       SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        SqlString document;
        try
        {
            // Set up the request, including authentication
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Convert.ToString(uri));
            if (Convert.ToString(username) != null & Convert.ToString(username) != "")
            {
                req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                    Convert.ToString(username),
                    Convert.ToString(passwd));
            }
            ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "CLR web client on SQL Server";

            // Fire off the request and retrieve the response.
            using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
            {

                using (Stream dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //SqlContext.Pipe.Send("...get the data");
                    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {
                        document = (SqlString)rdr.ReadToEnd();
                        rdr.Close();

                        //-----
                        string connectionString = null;
                        string sql = null;
                        connectionString = "Data source= 192.168.0.5; Database=Administration;User Id=Foo;Password=Blah; Trusted_Connection=True;";
                        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            sql = "INSERT INTO JSON_DATA (JSONROW) VALUES(@data)";
                            cnn.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                            {

                                String payload = "";
                                String nestpayload = "";
                                int nests = 0;
                                String json = document.ToString();
                                /*first lets do some housekeeping on our payload; double closing curly braces need to be escaped (with curly braces!) in order to keep them in the string.*/
                                json = json.Replace("\\", "");
                                int i = json.Length;
                                //return new SqlString(json);
                                while (i > 1)
                                {
                                    /*find the first closing "}" in the string and then check to see if there are more than one.
                                    We need to read the data up to each closing brace, pull off that substring and process it for each iteration until the string is gone.*/
                                    int closingbrace = json.IndexOf("}"); //First closing brace
                                    int nextbrace = Math.Max(0, json.IndexOf("{", closingbrace)); //Next opening brace
                                    String ChkVal = json.Substring(closingbrace + 1, Math.Max(1, nextbrace - closingbrace)); //+1 to ignore the 1st closing brace
                                    int checks = Math.Max(0, ChkVal.Length) - Math.Max(0, ChkVal.Replace("}", "").Length);
                                    payload = json.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, (json.IndexOf("}") + 1)));
                                    /*Remove the payload from the string*/
                                    json = json.Substring(payload.Length + 1);

                                    /*"nests" is how many nested levels excluding the opening brace for the closing brace we found.*/
                                    nests = (payload.Length - payload.Replace("{", "").Length);
                                    /*If we have more then one nest level check to see if any of them go with the payload*/

                                    if (nests > 1)
                                    {
                                        /*Break out the nested section and remove it from the payload.*/
                                        nestpayload = payload.Substring(0, payload.LastIndexOf("{"));
                                        payload = payload.Substring(payload.LastIndexOf("{"), payload.Length - payload.LastIndexOf("{"));

                                        while (nests > 1)
                                        {
                                            if (checks > 0) //# of right braces in payload equals number of left-side nests go with the payload
                                            {
                                                // payload = nestpayload.Substring(Math.Max(0, nestpayload.LastIndexOf("{")), Math.Max(0, nestpayload.Length) - Math.Max(0, (nestpayload.LastIndexOf("{")))) + payload;//The second Math.Max defaults to 1; if we got here there is at minimum one "{" character in the substring
                                                payload = nestpayload.Substring(nestpayload.LastIndexOf("{")) + payload;
                                                nestpayload = nestpayload.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, Math.Max(0, nestpayload.LastIndexOf("{"))));
                                                checks--;
                                                nests--;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                /*If we got here there are no more pieces of the nested data to append to the payload.
                                                 We use an array and string.split to keep the nest ordering correct.*/
                                                string[] OrderedNest = nestpayload.Split('{');
                                                for (int s = 0; s < OrderedNest.Length; s++)
                                                {
                                                    if (OrderedNest[s] != "")
                                                    {
                                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", "{" + OrderedNest[s].Replace(":", "}"));
                                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", nestpayload.Substring(Math.Max(0,nestpayload.LastIndexOf("{"))).Replace(":","}"));
                                                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", OrderedNest[1].Replace(":","}")+OrderedNest[2]);
                                                // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                                //cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                                                //nests = Math.Max(0, nests - 1);
                                                nests = 0;
                                                //nestpayload = nestpayload.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, Math.Max(0,nestpayload.LastIndexOf("{"))));

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }


                                    /*At the very end payload will be a single "}"; check for this and discard the last row*/
                                    if (payload != "}")
                                    {
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", new SqlChars(payload));
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                                    }

                                    /*Get the new string length*/
                                    i = json.Length;
                                    payload = "";

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        //-----

                        /*  }
                          catch (Exception e)
                          {
                              return e.ToString();
                          }*/
                    }

           // Close up everything...
                    dataStream.Close();
                }
                resp.Close();
                // .. and return the output to the caller.

            }//end using
            return ("Finished");
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {

            throw e;
        }                   
  }
}
```

While it works, it is INCREDIBLY slow; 4+ minutes to write 1500 rows to the server. Once daily this will need to write ~60,000 records in; the rest of the time it will be maybe 100 records POSTED and returned (I haven't worked up the POST part yet). I'm sure there are plenty of things I am doing not-so-proper here that are causing issues, but I have absolutely no idea where to even begin. I was excited enough that I could get the right response out of this! Any ideas/thoughts/help/sympathy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Begin by finding out what portion of the code is take the most time.  Add some test code that outputs the start and end times of each portion of the code.  I would be surprise to find out that the inserts to the database are the cause.  If it is the database then maybe the data base needs to be de-fragmented.  Are you using SQL Express or SQL Standard?  How large is the database?

Comment: @jdweng SQL Enterprise. 8 cores. This particular db is administrative only so quite small. Even so it is defragged regularly. Can you help me with some ideas about how to output the times? Am I outputting them back to the SQL server message window or is this something that must be done with debugger and the console window? I have VS2012 installed, when I try to debug I get that MSVMON.EXE error all the time. Still havent figured that out either!

Comment: I would start by deleting the bin folder (make a copy first) of your project.  This will force all your code to recompile.  The VS compiler doesn't always recognize library updates and your code may not be fully compatible with you current version of libraries.  I also do not like the 'using' statement because it does always report exceptions.  I rather use a try/catch and make sure I'm displaying all the exception messages. The using will continue past an exception with no error message and then you end up failing in the next block of code and looking for the error in the wrong block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here, not the least of which is that it appears you have posted your "sa" password to these here public interwebs. Here are the code issues that I see:

1. While it is possible to do Web Services calls in SQLCLR, it is definitely an advanced topic, full of pitfalls. This is not something that should be undertaken by a novice / beginner in SQLCLR, which itself is already a nuanced subset of regular .NET programming.
2. Get rid of the `SqlPipe` line and the comment line above it. Functions do not pass data back to the caller via `SqlPipe`; that is for Stored Procedures.
3. You probably shouldn't be using `WebRequest`
4. `document` should be `string`, not `SqlString`. You never return `document` and only ever convert it back to `string`, so it should just be that.
5. Use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebRequest`. This way you won't have to occasionally cast it into `HttpWebRequest`.
6. Don't convert the `SqlString` input parameters into `string` (e.g. `Convert.ToString(uri)`). All `Sql*` types have a `Value` property that returns the value in the native .NET type. So instead just use `uri.Value`, and so on.
7. Don't check for `NULL` inputs via `Convert.ToString(username) != null`. All `Sql*` type have an `IsNull` property that you can check. So instead use `!username.IsNull`.
8. DO NOT do all of your text processing (especially processing that contacts another system to do row-by-row inserts) while keeping the remote `HttpWebRequest` connection open. The *only* thing you should be doing within the `using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())` is populating the `document` variable. Don't do any processing of the contents of `document` until you are outside of that outer-most `using()`.
9. Don't do individual inserts (i.e. the `while (i > 1)` loop). They aren't even in a transaction. If you get an error in the middle of the document, you will have loaded partial data (unless that's ok for this process).
10. ALWAYS Schema-qualify database objects. Meaning, `JSON_DATA` should be `dbo.JSON_DATA` (or whatever Schema is being used if not `dbo`).
11. In your `connectionString` you have both Id/Password and `Trusted_Connection`. Don't use both as they are mutually exclusive options (if you have both, the Id/Password are ignored and only `Trusted_Connection` is used).
12. Please, please do not log in as `sa` or have your application log in as `sa`. That is just begging for a disaster.
13. Are you connecting to a different instance of SQL Server than this SQLCLR object is running on? If it is the same instance, you might be better off changing this into a `SqlProcedure` so that you can use `Context_Connection=True;` as the connection string. That is the in-process connection that attaches to the session that it is being called from.
14. Don't use `Parameters.AddWithValue()`. Bad idea. Create the SqlParameter with the specific, and appropriate, datatype. Then add is to the `Parameters` collection via `Add()`.

There might be other issues, but these were the obvious ones. As I said in point #1, you might be in over your head here. Not trying to be negative, just trying to avoid another poor implementation of SQLCLR that often leads to negative views of this otherwise very useful feature. If you want to pursue this, then please do more research first into how SQLCLR works, best practices, etc. A good place to start is a series that I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-sqlclr).

Or, another option is to use the **INET_GetWebPages** SQLCLR TVF that is available in the Full version of the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_50421702) SQLCLR library (which I wrote). This option is not free, but it would allow you to simply install the web request piece and then you just need to parse the returned document separately in a SQLCLR scalar UDF (which is probably the best approach anyway, even if you do the web request function / stored procedure on your own). In fact, if you are inserting into a table in the same Instance of SQL Server, you can create a SQLCLR TVF for the document parser and pass each `OrderedNest` value back using `yield return` (to stream the results back) and use as follows:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @JSON = [content]
FROM   SQL#.INET_GetWebPages(@uri, .....);

INSERT INTO dbo.JSON_DATA (JSONROW)
  SELECT [column_name]
  FROM   dbo.MyBrokenJsonFixerUpper(@JSON);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Oh the pitfalls of "copy-paste"!...thankfully just a test box, but fixed anyway. Yes, advanced, and yes I am saddled with it... sink or swim! Excellent comments, I will address each. No, we will not be using 'sa'; that was thrown in there early on to avoid permissions issues when initially testing. Great catch on the WebRequest being left open; think I need to look closer at how all of this is nested together. I am curious about better methods in regards to #9; should this be a bulk insert? I was staying away from that after reading about memory consumption etc for (the one) large data set.

Comment: Also... Can you expand a bit on why Parameters.AddWithValue is bad? Isn't the way I am doing it already setting the appropriate datatype? Wait, found this [link]https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/[/link]

Comment: @A.Guattery Yes, that blog post is most (or maybe all) of the issue. Also, just FYI, correcting the password is good, but keep in mind that the edit history of the question is publicly available via the "edit" link to the left of your name at the bottom of the question.  As for bulk inserting, yes, you could fill up a `DataTable` of the values and pass them all back at once via `SqlBulkCopy`, or you can do what I suggested of having a TVF spit back the result and do an `INSERT...SELECT` with it. Then you can set `DataAccessKind` to `None` which helps performance a little.

Comment: Interesting point about the "edit" link! I rewrote the code per our comments and have narrowed down the issue to the `IndexOf` and 
    `Substring` calls at the beginning of the `while (i < 1)` loop. The extremely large json string being recreated over and over is jamming up the works. i am thinking that it would be better if I create a     Datatable and split that string into it first. Then loop over that table and parse accordingly.

Comment: Hey there, @A.Guattery . Not sure you need a `DataTable` just to hold a list of strings. Couldn't you use a `string[]` or even `List<string>`? How many characters are these documents that you are getting from the web service?

Comment: the nightly pull is roughly 60,000 individual items so 60,000 individual strings that are 300-400 characters long each so the initial stream is 18-24Mb in length. I have considerably re-written this into a stored procedure (Thank you for the help thus far) and have it mostly working. It is quick (>15 seconds on the big pull!) but I am still working on error checking and proper try-catch-using syntax.

Comment: @A.Guattery Awesome. That is much better than 4 - 10 minutes!! And even better considering that your size calculation did not account for each character being 2 bytes in .NET (UTF-16LE, same as NVARCHAR in SQL Server). If you run this: `SELECT (60000 * 300 * 2) / 1024.0 / 1024.0, (60000 * 400 * 2) / 1024.0 / 1024.0;` you will see that the range is actually 34.33 MB to 45.78 MB. And you are quite welcome. Glad to have helped  .

Comment: @Solomon.Rutzky correct I did not include the 2-byte calculation; I figured you already knew that. :) And that 4-10 minutes was for a simple 17 line return! the large pull would have been more like 23+ HOURS by my math.

Comment: @A.Guattery Ah, ok. I wasn't sure since you stated the length in MB instead of characters. So I was just making sure. All good. And yeesh, 23+ hours? I misread the question then. I thought it was 4 minutes for 1500 rows and that it would really be doing 60k rows, which I guess is 40x more, and 40 times 4 minutes certainly ain't 10 minutes ;-). So either way I was off. So wow, even better than I originally thought in terms of the improvement. So, to be clear, the "big pull", which could have taken 23+ hours, now looks like it will take how long?

Comment: @Solomon.Rutsky I am returning the the LARGE pull in 12-14 seconds! The only thing I am struggling with at the moment is removing consecutive closing `}`. In order to make it very easy (and FAST) for SQL server to parse the string results I need to balance the opening and closing braces but this `l.Replace("}", "");` does not work. At the end of some strings there will be 2 or more consecutive braces...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171716/discussion-between-a-guattery-and-solomon-rutzky).

Answer (score 1):

I am marking this question answered as it has become clear that what was need is a rewrite and rethinking of my original script. @Solomon Rutzky upvoted for providing helpful information which pointed me to this conclusion. For those 
interested here is the rewrite:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
// Other things we need for WebRequest
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ApiParser(SqlString uri, SqlString user, SqlString pwd, SqlString postd)
    {
        // Create an SqlPipe to send data back to the caller
        SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        //Make sure we have a url to process
        if (uri.IsNull || uri.Value.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            pipe.Send("uri cannot be empty");
            return;
        }
    try
    {
        //Create our datatable and get the table structure from the database
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string connectionString = null;
        //connectionString = "Data source= 192.168.0.5; Database=Administration; Trusted_Connection=True;";
        connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        using (SqlConnection gts = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            gts.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM sp_WebSvcs.dbo.JSON_DATA", gts))
            {
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }
        }

        // Send a message string back to the client.
        pipe.Send("Beginning Api Call...");
        String json = "";
        // Set up the request, including authentication
        WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri.Value);
        if (!user.IsNull & user.Value != "")
        {
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user.Value, pwd.Value);
        }
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "CLR web client on SQL Server";

        // Fire off the request and retrieve the response.
        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
        {

            using (Stream dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {

                using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    json = (String)rdr.ReadToEnd();

                    rdr.Close();
                }

                // Close up everything...
                dataStream.Close();
            }
            resp.Close();

        }//end using resp
        pipe.Send("Api Call complete; Parsing returned data...");
        int i = 0;
        String h = "";
        String l = "";
        int s = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int payload = 0;
        foreach (string line in json.Split(new[] { "}," }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            if (line != "")
            {
                l = line;
                i = l.Replace("{", "").Length + 1;
                p = l.LastIndexOf("{");
                if (line.Length > i) //we find this at the beginning of a group of arrays
                {

                    h = line.Substring(0, p - 1);
                    s = Math.Max(0, h.LastIndexOf("{"));
                    if (h.Length > s && s != 0)
                    /*We have a nested array that has more than one level.
                     *This should only occur at the beginning of new array group.
                     *Advance the payload counter and get the correct string from line.*/
                    {
                        payload++;
                        l = line.Substring(s, line.Length - s);
                    }


                    h = (s >= 0) ? h.Substring(0, s) : h;
                    //=============
                    /*At this point 'h' is a nest collection. Split and add to table.*/
                    string[] OrderedNest = h.Split('{');
                    for (int z = 0; z < OrderedNest.Length; z++)
                    {
                        if (OrderedNest[z] != "")
                        {
                            table.Rows.Add(payload, "{" + OrderedNest[z].Replace(":", "").Replace("[","").Replace("]","") + "}");
                        }
                    }
                    //=============

                }
                else
                {
                    h = null;
                }
                //at this point the first character in the row should be a "{"; If not we need to add one.
                if (l[0].ToString() != "{")
                {
                    l = "{" + l;
                }

                if (l.Replace("{", "").Length != l.Replace("}", "").Length) //opening and closing braces don't match; match the closing to the opening
                {
                    l = l.Replace("}", "");

                    b = l.Length - l.Replace("{", "").Length;

                    l = l + new String('}', b);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(payload, l.Replace("\\\"", "").Replace("\\", "").Replace("]","").Replace("[",""));

            }
        }
        //====

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cnn))
            {
                copy.DestinationTableName = "sp_WebSvcs.dbo.JSON_DATA";
                copy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
        }
        //====

    } //end try
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        pipe.Send("We have a problem!");
        throw new Exception("\n\n" + e.Message + "\n\n");
    }
    pipe.Send("Parsing complete");

}
```

}